# Why does www-data need execute access to write uploaded files to a directory?

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-20.04

When anyone learning approaches the task of setting permissions on a media upload folder that is destined for public access they might instinctively think that it should be set to `777` or `666` due to all the incorrect tutorials that exist out in the wild.

So, today I decided that I wanted to understand the whole idea of setting correct/secure folder access permissions.

I discovered that on my Ubuntu 20.04 server I needed to assign `700` (or `770` if the owner is a real user) to allow uploads with `move_uploaded_file()`.

Why does `www-data` need `execute` access to `write` the file?

My best assumption is that because `move_uploaded_file()` is a function of PHP it is essentially executing that function within the destination folder (even though the actual call to that function is in an entirely different folder/file location).

Since I'm never correct in my first assumptions, I decided to ask.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work Should help you out. Though the link talks about the rwx permissions, you need to know the numerical versions. 4 is read (r), 2 is write (w), 1 is execute (x), and you'd add them up to get the numbers. 7 is read/write/execute, 6 is read/write, 0 is nothing at all.

Comment: @barmar, well, actually it has everything to do with PHP and if you even read the post you can clearly see that I mention the PHP function `move_uploaded_file()`. Thanks for playing though! You get a participation award!

Note: Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Outdated comments may get deleted. [Learn more about comments…](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: for directory I'm always use `sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;`

Comment: I am surprised that they did not remove this question for you. As I once asked `chmod 770 for directory`, they deleted it and wrote `lern chmod`:):)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that for directories, the execute bit is used for access to files in that directory. The read permission is used for listing the content. Take this example:

```
johan@eden:~/example$ mkdir test
johan@eden:~/example$ echo 123 > test/example.txt
johan@eden:~/example$ cat test/example.txt 
123
johan@eden:~/example$ chmod a-x test
johan@eden:~/example$ cat test/example.txt 
cat: test/example.txt: Permission denied
```

#### Summary

**read:**
Allowed to list the contents of the directory.

**write:**
Allowed to create, modify or delete files in the directory.

**execute:**
Allowed to access a file in the directory if you know the name of the file.

Comment: This is a good answer. When the PHP engine needs to access the target folder with `move_uploaded_file()` it's permission to execute is checked by the system because technically it's executing the function `move_uploaded_file()` inside that folder. I wonder if you could use nano to write to that folder without execute permissions since it's a system level event as opposed to a third party script event.

Comment: @EthanAaronVandal Not sure if that is correct, in my understanding, any access to example.txt is blocked, even system level events (from a user missing the execute bit on the folder).

Comment: So then you always need execute to create or modify? Because those two actions would constitute access, right?

Comment: That's right. You can just test it in a terminal if you don't agree.. :)